# Project version control organization with multiple private entities contributing

Tags: mercurial, bitbucket

I am looking for suggestions on how to best organize this environment descried below.  We are currently on Mercurial and I would prefer to stay there, however if a different version control system will help us achieve our goals, we will switch.

Short summary - Our company has been contracting another company to do work.  I have been merging from our shared repository to our private repository where we have other modifications, and building a release product from there.  Now we want to add 2 more contractors (who are entire companies, not just a guy) that can also contribute, however all contractors have private information that I can see, but needs to be private from the other contractors.

More details:

ContractorA started repository
I forked ContractorA to MyCompany

MyCompany now contains additions to ContractorA

The way I have been handling this so far is this:

ContractorA pushes to ContractorA
My Local machine has a clone of MyCompany
I have an alias to ContractorA on my local machine
I Pull from ContractorA, handle any merge conflicts, and then push to MyCompany

So the MyCompany repo has all changes from ContractorA and MyCompany

This has been working perfect for my needs, however now ContractorB is going to enter the picture

ContractorA has proprietary stuff that ContractorB cant have access to and ContractorB has proprietary stuff that Contractor A can’t have access to.

There is a common section that ContractorA will be contributing to and MyCompany and ContractorB will be using.

Everything needs to end up in MyCompany as we do 1 build that will include everything - 
Common code that ContractorA modifies
Proprietary code from ContractorA
Proprietary code from ContractorB
Common Code from MyCompany

Any thoughts on how to handle this?

Since MyCompany is a clone of ContractorA, I cannot just give access to ContractorB to MyCompany Repo, correct?  Or is there a way to restrict access on a directory basis to each user?

Is there a way to fork MyCompany into a new repository ContractorB and remove all ContractorA proprietary code such that ContractorB can never see any ContractorA proprietary code.  If that is the case, could I put another alias in my local machine, pull from ContractorA, merge and push to MyCompany, then pull from ContractorB, merge and push to MyCompany?

Does this make any sense at all?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a Mercurial repo, you will need to have full and complete access to the entire history of the working directory. However, you can `hg clone` a repo and only include certain branches in the clone and as long as you are careful about how those branches interact, you can achieve your goal. You do have a couple options and I've listed them in order of how I would rank them:

1. **Each does their work on separate branches** You will need four branches: `core`, `branch-a`, `branch-b`, `composed-branch`. All merges between the branches *must* go only one way: `core` -> `branch-a` -> `composed-branch`.

   - `core`: the common code base that is shared by all. All updates to this code need to be done at the `tip` of `core` since you will *never* be merging any other branches into it. If you make updates to the shared codebase, you then merge it into each contractor branch. If a contractor does anything  on their own branch that should be put into core, manually make the updates to core via copy/paste or via a patch.
   - `branch-a` and `branch-b`: these hold the independent work done by the separate contractors. The public repo to which ContractorA has access (for pushes and pulls) will only have changes `core` and `branch-a` present since those are the only ancestors of the `tip` of their branch. Similarly for the ContractorB's repo.
   - `composed-branch`: this is where the magic happens. You pull from `branch-a` and `branch-b` and merge them into this branch as you receive updates from the contractors. You handle any merge conflicts here and can also do any additional changes to integrate the work done by the contractors. This is the branch that your build system pulls.
2. **Break your current repo into several smaller repos** If the risk of an incorrect push with one repo is too great or if the work each contractor is more like a `dll` or a library that can be built independently, it may make more sense to treat them as independent repos. Basically the previous suggestion, but independent repos instead of independant branches. You would again separate things into "used by all", "created by contractor" and "combined total". Also note that you may find hg's [sub-repo](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/Subrepository) useful, though it is considered a "feature of last resort".
3. **Do it all via patches** Contractors can send you updates as exported patches and you can apply and clean them up. This is a bad idea so I won't go into details unless pressed, but it is possible.

In all cases, you will likely need to start a new repo based on your current codebase that cleans the boundaries about what goes into `core` and can be seen by all.

**Note: even if you `hg delete` files in the repo, they are still fully accessible in the history!**

Comment: Edward - Thank you!
your option 1 sounds very close to what I need!  Does HG support user permissions by branch?  Or should I clone with the branch for ContractorA, then fork that cloned repo and then give ContractorA access to that one?  Thank you so much for your insight!

Comment: Yup. `hg clone -b ContractorA ...` will result in a forked repo that only contains the ancestors of branch `ContractorA`'s tip. You could add a [`prechangegroup` hooks](http://hgbook.red-bean.com/read/handling-repository-events-with-hooks.html)  to the ContractorA's shared repo that only allows the  `core` and `branch-a` for additional security, but you've got the basic idea.

Answer (score 0):

If every contractor **must** get another contractor work except "secret part", you have

- Have MQ extension enabled on MyCompany repo
- Move  all secret parts of every contractor into separate MQ-patch (one patch per contractor)
- (Clone|push to contractor's repo) with **only his** patch applied (hook can help with such condition-check)
- Your integrator's work must be performed with both patches applied to MyCompany repo